# JUnit Passing No arguments to main Method Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I'm trying to test my main method (which should accept exactly one argument) for no arguments passed. Can't seem to understand what am I missing here to achieve that.The nature of my program is such that it reads input from a file, creates objects by passing parameters read from the file, and displays output.

> Failure Message:
>
> org.junit.ComparisonFailure:   Expected :Please pass one argument
>
> Actual   :

Here's my Unit Test:

```
    @Test
    public void givenNoParameter_shouldAskForOne() throws IOException {
    String[] args = {};
    String output;

    try (ByteArrayOutputStream bOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(bOutput));
        Main.main(args);
        bOutput.flush();
        output = bOutput.toString();
    }
    String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    String[] breakDownOutput = output.split(newLine);

    assertEquals(1, breakDownOutput.length);
    assertEquals("Please pass one argument", breakDownOutput[0]);
}
```

Main Method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    if(args.length == 1) {
        DisplayOrder.setFilePath(args[0]);
        DisplayOrder.display();
    } else{
        System.err.println("Please pass one argument");
    }
}
```

I've realized I was using System.err.println() in my main. Changing that to System.out.println() fixed it.

Comment: Show the `main` method code

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: And just for the record: testing system.out like that is really a bad idea. You rather want to write code that returns strings for example, or where simply **pass in** the output stream to write to.

Comment: In some special cases, like writing a test harness for CodinGame (or equivalent coding platform) exercices, testing `System.out` is the only way.

Comment: Sorry folks. I've edited my question and added the main method.

Comment: @LoïcLeDoyen : It is indeed an application that takes inputs via a file and prints output

Comment: You passed it a zero length array. Your code is working as designed.

Answer (score 1):

Not showing your main method, my only guess is, that you do not write anything to "System.out" in your main, especially there is no `System.out.println("Please pass one argument");` statement which is executed.
So, your unit test fails perfectly for a not expected value in "`breakDownOutput[0]`".

What you have to do is to make certain that the `System.out.println("Please pass one argument");` is executed if no arguments were provided to your main.
Also check your class name `Main.main(...)` since there might be other `Main` classes imported which will never print out your expected values to `System.out`

Comment: When I run the code from the IDE without passing any arguments, System.out.println("Please pass one argument"); gets executed. But what I'm trying here is to figure out how to pass no arguments in this test.